# how to edit pixels and remove white background in a canvas image in html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If I load an image, how can I loop through all its pixels and turn the white ones (or which ever color I specify) to be turned transparent?

I have an idea on how to do this, but the looping process should be like a 2d array, so it would involve two for loops.

I was thinking I would start on the top row first pixel, iterating to the right, if its a white pixel, then i turn it transparent, and move 1 pixel to the right, if its not white, then   I stop. Then in the same row, I start from the left most pixel, and check, if white, I turn it transparent, then move 1 pixel to the left, etc, etc...

Then I move 1 row down and repeat the whole process..

This way I don't remove any white pixels in the actual image.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Its pretty simple to do using `getImageData` and `putImageData` just note you can take a pretty significant hit on performance the larger the image gets. You just need to determine if the current pixel is white, then change its alpha to 0.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/BtbSM/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = document.getElementById("testImage");

canvas.height = canvas.width = 135;
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 135, 135),
    pix = imgd.data,
    newColor = {r:0,g:0,b:0, a:0};

for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
    var r = pix[i],
            g = pix[i+1],
            b = pix[i+2];

        // If its white then change it
        if(r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255){ 
            // Change the white to whatever.
            pix[i] = newColor.r;
            pix[i+1] = newColor.g;
            pix[i+2] = newColor.b;
            pix[i+3] = newColor.a;
        }
}

ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);​
```

It was also asked if you could make the values sort of fuzzy to check. Its really easy, just check if its in a certain range. The following will turn off white to pure white transparent.

```
 // If its white or close then change it
    if(r >=230 && g >= 230 && b >= 230){ 
        // Change the white to whatever.
        pix[i] = newColor.r;
        pix[i+1] = newColor.g;
        pix[i+2] = newColor.b;
        pix[i+3] = newColor.a;
    }
```

**More resources**

- [Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas/)
- [Further info on pixel manipulation with canvas](http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/)

Comment: Check out [this](http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/) post for a tutorial on this subject for more information.

Comment: This would change all the white pixels in the image but we want to remove only the background pixels which are white , right ?

Comment: @user1416970 ah your right I just changed it to turn all white pixels transparent.

Comment: also is it possible to have a tolerance to remove pixels that are very close to white? This way it will remove those pixels that get left behind.

Comment: @user1497454 yeah totally possible, let me edit my answer to show that.

Answer (score 10):

You can use an image processing framework to not handle pixel data manually.

In the case of [MarvinJ](https://www.marvinj.org), given a color, you can set all pixels to transparent with a single line:

```
image.setColorToAlpha(0, 0);
```

**Input image**:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Runnable Example:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
image = new MarvinImage();
image.load("https://i.imgur.com/UuvzbLx.png", imageLoaded);

function imageLoaded(){
 image.setColorToAlpha(0, 0); 
 image.draw(canvas);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.8.js"></script>
<div style="width:400px; height:352px;  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%),
 linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%),
 linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%), 
 linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%);
 background-size: 20px 20px;
 background-position: 0 0, 0 10px, 10px -10px, -10px 0px;">
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="352"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loktar may have a method that 'works', but it's performance is rather dismal. This can be a problem if you have lots of images, you don't want your website to drain laptop/mobile-devices batteries, or if you just want speed. Here is a method that works far more efficiently. Click on the "Run Code Snippet" button for a demo of it in action.

```js
'use-strict'
let fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput'),
  theCANVAS = document.getElementById('theCanvas'),
  theCANVASctx = theCANVAS.getContext('2d'),
  imgTMP = document.getElementById('imgTMP'),
  rComponent = document.getElementById('r'),
  gComponent = document.getElementById('g'),
  bComponent = document.getElementById('b'),
  aComponent = document.getElementById('a'),
  transColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
  transCode = 0xffffffff;

let makeColorTransparent =
  function(canvasContext, transparentID, width, height) {
    // where all the magic happens
    let theImageData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
      theImageDataBufferTMP = new ArrayBuffer(theImageData.data.length),
      theImageDataClamped8TMP = new Uint8ClampedArray(theImageDataBufferTMP),
      theImageDataUint32TMP = new Uint32Array(theImageDataBufferTMP),
      n = theImageDataUint32TMP.length;
    theImageDataClamped8TMP.set(theImageData.data);

    imgDataLoop: while (n--) {
      // effciency at its finest:
      if (theImageDataUint32TMP[n] !== transparentID)
        continue imgDataLoop;
      theImageDataUint32TMP[n] = 0x00000000; // make it transparent
    }
    theImageData.data.set(theImageDataClamped8TMP);
    theCANVASctx.putImageData(theImageData, 0, 0);
  },
  downloadCanvas = function(downloadfilename) {
    theCanvas.toBlob(function(theIMGblob) {
      var thedataURL = URL.createObjectURL(theIMGblob),
        theAtagLink = document.createElement('a');

      theAtagLink.download = '(proccessed)' + downloadfilename;
      document.body.appendChild(theAtagLink);
      theAtagLink.href = thedataURL;
      theAtagLink.click();
    });
  };

fileInput.onchange = function(fileevent) {
  let efiles = fileevent.target.files,
    localTransColor = transColor,
    localTransCode = transCode;

  let cur = efiles.length,
    nextfile = function() {
      if (!cur--) {
        imgTMP.src = '';
        return;
      }
      let fr = new FileReader();
      console.log(efiles[cur]);
      fr.onload = function(dataevt) {
        fr.onload = null;
        let theArrayBuffer = dataevt.target.result,
          theblob = new Blob([theArrayBuffer]);
        imgTMP.src = URL.createObjectURL(theblob);
        imgTMP.onload = function() {
          imgTMP.onload = null;
          let theImagesWidth = imgTMP.naturalWidth,
            theImagesHeight = imgTMP.naturalHeight;

          theCANVAS.width = theImagesWidth;
          theCANVAS.height = theImagesHeight;

          theCANVASctx.fillStyle = localTransColor;
          theCANVASctx.clearRect(
            0,
            0,
            theImagesWidth,
            theImagesHeight
          );
          theCANVASctx.drawImage(imgTMP, 0, 0);
          makeColorTransparent(
            theCANVASctx,
            localTransCode,
            theImagesWidth,
            theImagesHeight
          );

          //now, download the file:
          downloadCanvas(efiles[cur].name);

          //Finally, procced to proccess the next file
          nextfile();
        };
      };
      fr.readAsArrayBuffer(efiles[cur]);
    };
  nextfile();
}

rComponent.oninput = gComponent.oninput =
  bComponent.oninput = aComponent.oninput =
  function() {
    rComponent.value = Math.max(0, Math.min(rComponent.value, 255));
    gComponent.value = Math.max(0, Math.min(gComponent.value, 255));
    bComponent.value = Math.max(0, Math.min(bComponent.value, 255));
    aComponent.value = Math.max(0, Math.min(aComponent.value, 255));
  };

rComponent.onchange = gComponent.onchange =
  bComponent.onchange = aComponent.onchange =
  function() {
    transColor = 'rgba(' +
      rComponent.value + ',' +
      gComponent.value + ',' +
      bComponent.value + ',' +
      aComponent.value / 255 + ',' +
      ')';
    // numberical equivelent of the rgba
    transCode =
      rComponent.value * 0x00000001 +
      gComponent.value * 0x00000100 +
      bComponent.value * 0x00010000 +
      aComponent.value * 0x01000000;
  };
```

```html
<pre>rgba(<input type="number" value="255" max="255" min="0" step="1" id="r" maxlength="3" minlength="1" />,<input type="number" value="255" max="255" min="0" step="1" id="g" maxlength="3" minlength="1" />,<input type="number" value="255" max="255" min="0" step="1" id="b" maxlength="3" minlength="1" />,<input type="number" value="255" max="255" min="0" step="1" id="a" maxlength="3" minlength="1" />)</pre>

<input type="file" name="filefield" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" id="fileInput" /><br />
<img id="imgTMP" />
<canvas id="theCanvas"></canvas>

<style>input[type=number]{width: 3em}#theCanvas {display: none}</style>
```